# Laravel Eloquentでuser_idが取得できない

Tags: php, laravel

**現在の状況**

1. Eloquentでの記述の場合に『user_idがnull』とエラーが出る。
2. ログイン自体は成功しており、同ページで@if (Auth::check)を用いた文も正常に機能
   ３.コメントアウトしている記述ならば問題なくテーブルに保存が行える。

なぜ現状のコードでは[user_id]が取得出来ないのでしょうか。
どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

また、追記必要なファイルがあればコメントで指摘していただければ幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Lost;

class LostsController extends Controller
{
    public function add(){
        $user = Auth::user();

        return view('lost.size_small',['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {

        $lost = new Lost;
        $form = $request->all();
        unset($form['_token']);
        $lost->fill($form)->save();
        return redirect('/');

        /*
        $lost = new Lost;
        $lost->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $lost->pref = $request->pref;
        $lost->seed = $request->seed;
        $lost->image = $request->image;
        $lost->body = $request->body;
        $lost->save();
        return redirect('/select');
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: formの中身はどうなっているでしょう、そこにuser_idは無いかと思いますが……（そもそももしフォームで投げていてもそれを使うのは危険ですが）

Comment: あ、そうそう。質問タイトルからしてもしや誤解されているのかもしれませんが、`Request`はモデル(Eloquent)ではありませんし、そのuserは当然リレーションではありません

Comment: @hinaloe ご指摘ありがとうございます,formにはuser_idを指定する欄は作ってはいません。user_idを取得する場合はコメントアウトしている記述で取得するのが普通なのでしょうか？

Comment: アプローチは複数ありますが、基本的にはそうですね。あるいはリレーションのassignをつかって`$lost->user()->assign($request->user())`のようにすることもできますね。

Comment: @hinaloe ありがとうございます！　通常の現場でも問題は無い記述でしょうか？転職のポートフォリオとして作成しているので、ご教授願いたいです

Comment: 問題ありません、というかデザインパターンこそ色々ありますがActiveRecordライクなモデルでは結局はどこかでおなじようなことをしてるかと。なおfillableにすべきはユーザー入力可能なものだけにするとか……

Comment: 上でassignと書いてしまっていましたが`associate`ですね

Answer (score 1):

コメントでも少し書きましたが、当然ながら`Request`はモデルではありません。
`$request->all()`はリクエストのクエリとリクエスト本文のパラメータをまとめて返します。

とりあえず当該部分は以下に抜粋してみます。

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9abc0896070176fd6987d95f0d1b50de947db82c/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L179-L210

```
    /**
     * Get the keys for all of the input and files.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function keys()
    {
        return array_merge(array_keys($this->input()), $this->files->keys());
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the input and files for the request.
     *
     * @param  array|mixed|null  $keys
     * @return array
     */
    public function all($keys = null)
    {
        $input = array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->allFiles());

        if (! $keys) {
            return $input;
        }

        $results = [];

        foreach (is_array($keys) ? $keys : func_get_args() as $key) {
            Arr::set($results, $key, Arr::get($input, $key));
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9abc0896070176fd6987d95f0d1b50de947db82c/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L359-L371

```
    /**
     * Get the input source for the request.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag
     */
    protected function getInputSource()
    {
        if ($this->isJson()) {
            return $this->json();
        }

        return in_array($this->getRealMethod(), ['GET', 'HEAD']) ? $this->query : $this->request;
    }
```

一方、`$request->user()`はUserProviderを呼び出します。
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9abc0896070176fd6987d95f0d1b50de947db82c/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L509-L518

```
    /**
     * Get the user making the request.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function user($guard = null)
    {
        return call_user_func($this->getUserResolver(), $guard);
    }
```

---

ですから、質問のようなコードでは当然ながら`user_id`はわたりません。
Requestからユーザーを取得するにはコメントアウト部にあるよう`$request->user()`を使用します。
もし、当該のbelongsToリレーションが設定されているのであれば、

```
$lost->fill($form);
$lost->user()->associate($user);
$lost->save();
```

あるいは

```
$lost->fill($form)->user()->associate($user)->save();
```

のように書くことすら可能です。

https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/eloquent-relationships.html