# laravel sql エラー: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

現在laravelでタスクリストを作ってます。
user_idカラムを追加しましたが、下記エラーが出ます。
考えられる原因を教えてもらいたいです。
ソースコードはどのソースコードを載せればいいのかわからないです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`status`, `content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

Task.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['content', 'status', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

TasksController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        if (\Auth::check()) {
            $user = \Auth::user();
            $tasks = $user->tasks()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')>paginate(10);

            $data = [
                'user' => $user,
                'tasks' => $tasks,
            ];

            return view('tasks.index', [
                'tasks' => $tasks,
            ]);

        } else {
            return view('welcome');    
        }

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $task = new Task;

        return view('tasks.create', [
            'task' => $task,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'status' => 'required|max:10',
            'content' => 'required|max:191',
        ]);

        $task = new Task;
        $task->status = $request->status;
        $task->content = $request->content;
        $task->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($id);

        return view('tasks.show', [
            'task' => $task,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($id);

        return view('tasks.edit', [
            'task' => $task,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'status' => 'required|max:10',
            'content' => 'required|max:191',
        ]);

        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->status = $request->status;
        $task->content = $request->content;
        $task->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->delete();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: とりあえず当該のコントローラーのコードがほしいところでしょうか、あとTaskのモデル。あと何らかの参考資料があるでしょうので是非教えて下さい。状況としてはリレーション先のユーザーがセットされていない、みたいな状況でしょうが……

Comment: 質問に補足を追加する際は質問文を編集してください

Comment: ところで先日似たような質問があったのを忘れていました…… https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61169/2376

Comment: 別の質問を教えていただきありがとうございます。確認しましたが、sqlのエラー内容が違い少し違うのかなって思ってます。私の理解が浅いので、しっかり理解出来ないかもしれませんが。。。

Comment: エラーが違うのはMySQLとSQLite（かな）の差っぽいですね。まあこのfillを使わない書き方をしているのであれば当該の質問でコメントアウトされているコードが参考になる部分ですが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問を参考に修正したら、sqlエラー解消されました。DBの違いはよくわかりませんが、紹介いただいた質問の方と同じエラーもこちらで確認しました。私の場合は記述方法が少し間違えてた時に同じエラーが出ました。丁寧にご指摘いただきありがとうございました。また質問するかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーを見る限りは user_id が not null (NULL価を許容しない)カラム
で default 価もないのに価がセットされてないのでエラーになってるんだと思います

修正方法は user_id というのが null を許容するのかどうかに依存します

許容するならマイグレーションで null 値を許容する修正マイグレーションをうちます

許容しないなら laravel 内のコードでモデル作製時に user_id を渡す必要があります

Comment: user_idはnot nullです。エラーの内容までは理解してますが、このエラーの解消方がわかりません。1から作り直すのも問題無いですが、現状php artisan migrate:fresh等でもエラーが出て実行出来ません。コードモデル作成時にuser_idをどの様に渡せますか？

Comment: `$task->status = $request->status; $task->content = $request->content;`　のところに user_id も追加すればいいかと思います。request で渡すのか内部で取得するのかなぜuser_idが必要なのかロジックまではわかりません

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。$task->user_id = $request->user()->id;を追記することで、sqlエラー解消されました。ありがとうございました。